# A different approach to finding the area of a triangle

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to find the area of a triangle with just the circumradius and inradius?

Comment: It's not at all a bad question, but this is not a good site for it. It would surely be received better at MSE.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not! $R,r,p=\frac{a+b+c}2$ decide a triangle